# Sum Calculation: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1- \frac{\cosh^{-1} n}{\log 2x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, summation, approximation, hyperbolic-functions

I was investigating the asymptotic properties of the $\cosh$ functions and how they all strongly relate to $e^x$

In my studying, I found out that $\cosh x\sim \frac{e^x}{2}$

By that definition, that must also mean that $\cosh^{-1} x\sim \log 2x$

From that finding, I wanted to a bit deeper into the approximation, but without the use of Big Oh's.

That led me to the sum of my question:

What is the closed form to $$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1- \frac{\cosh^{-1} n}{\log 2n}\right)$$

W|A could not evaluate the sum, but did come up with an approximation to it. That approximation is $I=1.09258$

Comment: Why makes you suspect that there is a closed form for the series?

Comment: @Dr.MV Because I think that it is underestimated just how many sums have closed forms.

Comment: John.  Why do you believe that this one does?

Comment: @Dr.MV The point I am trying to make is that it should be a question of why shouldn't it have a closed form, in contrast to your question. What exactly is your reason against a closed form?

Comment: Even the corresponding integral seems not to have a closed form solution what makes it really unlikely that the sum has one